# camera capture looks different on windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, opencv3.0

hey im trying to use a raspberry pi with opencv to prosses some images but while i am capturing the images from the webcam using the same values using windows on my pc and Ubuntu mate on the pi they look very different

[linux capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09PrR.jpg)

[windows capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfJug.png)

does anyone know why there any difference

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your usb webcam probably has a compatibility problem with the pi (or its drivers in Ubuntu mate).

Try googling the camera model and linux compatibility to see if there are any known tricks to do.

Googling "raspberry pi usb camera compatibility" gives you various lists of known compatible cameras.

In terms of performance (e.g. frame rate) a usb webcam is always worse than the raspberry pi camera attached to the camera serial interface.

To get that working in opencv, you can use this library:

RaspiCam: C++ API for using Raspberry camera with/without OpenCv

www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40